# TrueCrypt and PCManFM

Tags: lubuntu, truecrypt, pcmanfm

The LXDE FM won't show the volume after mounting it in TrueCrypt. Found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=918916#p918916) and [this](http://www.overclock.net/t/1015229/truecrypt-assistance). Is there any recommended way?

Comment: Since I read in the Arch-forum (link) that TrueCrypt calls Nautilus by:`/usr/bin/nautilus --no-default-window --no-desktop /media/truecrypt1`, I tried to put `#!/bin/bash
exec pcmanfm $3
exit 0` into the file as recommended. Doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to specify the mount point and then navigate to the mount point.

Example:

I have an encrypted file named "enc1" at "/home/desgua/Dropbox", and my mount point is the folder "/mnt/mymountpoint/", so I type this on terminal:

`truecrypt --mount /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1 /mnt/mymountpoint/`

And then navigate to "/mnt/mymountpoint/" to see my files.

And to unmount:

`truecrypt -d /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1`

or simple:

`truecrypt -d`  (which should unmount every truecrypted mounted files)

**Outside command line**

*Suggestion One*

You can edit the file /etc/fstab (open it with `gksu gedit /etc/fstab`) and add a line to specify the mount point:

`/dev/sda1/home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1 /mnt/mymountpoint  auto   rw,user 0      0`

Reboot.

Now you can mount through GUI and navigate to /mnt/mymountpoint

More info [here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/TrueCrypt).

*Suggestion Two*

Also you can create a launcher to mount it:

1) Paste this at terminal: `gedit ~/Desktop/unmounttruecrypt.desktop`,

2) Then paste this into the file and save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Unmount Truecrypt
Comment=Unmount all mounted Truecrypt files
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"truecrypt --mount /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1 /mnt/mymountpoint/ ; exit; exec bash\""
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/48/go-jump.svg
Categories=Application;Accessories;
```

3) Now look at your desktop and drag the file to the Launcher.

Comment: There's no way outside of the command line? What would you enter in order to unmount?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You will have to edit the fstab file. To unmount through command line use `truecrypt -d`

Comment: Should I add the line to fstab the way it is or do I have to change anything except your username to mine, like "/mnt/mymountpoint" to something else or "user" to my username? Here's what I got: `/dev/sda1/home/arno/Secret /home/arno auto rw,user 0 0`

Comment: I would suggest you to set an empty folder to be the mount point: `/dev/sda1/home/arno/Secret /home/arno/mnt auto rw,user 0 0`

Comment: I'm sorry I think I'm messing it all up. I added the line above to fstab, but it won't mount the container there. Instead I get an error upon boot that /home/arno is not present. I also created the launcher, but dragging the file on it neither mounts the container nor unmounts it. I think I'll stick to the CL version. It's just that I think it's slow to type it every time :D

Comment: You could create a shortcut with a command like this: `gnome-terminal -e "bash -c \"truecrypt --mount /home/desgua/Dropbox/enc1 /mnt/mymountpoint/; exit; exec bash\""`

Comment: To create a shortcut: System > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Add